# How to solve "the package is of bad quality" ubuntu software center

Tags: linux, ubuntu, deb

I have the following deb-control:

```
$cat control
Package: Deb-Package
Version: 2016-Jan-24
Architecture: all
Installed-Size: 252000
Homepage: http://www.google.com
Maintainer: My Name <myemail@gmail.com>
Description: my deb package
```

and after create my deb package with the command:

```
dpkg-deb --build <folder>
```

and then when I try to install it on the ubuntu software center I always get the following notification: "The package is of bad quality ".

How to avoid this dialog ?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/111959/what-is-a-bad-quality-package

Comment: im looking for example an additional line of code, or something like that, because i would like to install this deb package in the ubuntu center software without this message previously mentioned, so i had already seen this post but it does not help me

Comment: Did you run the linter and check your package against the policies?

Comment: ok, good anwer, but look like that i have several errors after run these command

Answer (score 1):

At least your package name is invalid. Quoting the manual at https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html:

> Package names (both source and binary, see Package, Section 5.6.7)
>   must consist only of lower case letters (a-z), digits (0-9), plus (+)
>   and minus (-) signs, and periods (.). They must be at least two
>   characters long and must start with an alphanumeric character.

Therefore `Deb-Package` is not allowable, as it contains 2 uppercase characters.

Technically your version string is allowed, but you should keep in mind that it represents Debian revision `24` of version `2016-Jan` of your package. You would do better [following conventions there too](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-Version).

Apart from these 2 your control file seems right, but more might be wrong in the package contents itself. In general, [Lintian](https://lintian.debian.org/) should return no errors, although many small violations are permissible - I have several packages in a private apt repository with errors although they work fine. I do suspect the package name violation is fatal though.

Comment: as well i noticed that the package name is invalid, so i changed this field, i have a question, when i open my deb package in ubuntu center i wonder how to apply an image to shows there ?

Comment: No clue, I only use Debian itself. Package manager is the same, never seen Ubuntu software center in my life though  :)